# RecyclerView Adapter change selected position in List Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In `RecyclerView.Adapter` i need to change `favIcon` in each row list that after select each position just specified row `favIcon` change.

All thing is right but when scroll RecyclerView , position of selected row change automatically!

it's my adapter class :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ItemData[] itemsData;
Activity activity;

public MyAdapter(Activity activity, ItemData[] itemsData) {
    this.activity=activity;
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!viewHolder.isFav) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Selected Row : "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.isFav = true;
                viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fav);
            } else {
                viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pre_ic_ab_drawer);
                viewHolder.isFav = false;
            }
        }
    });


    if (viewHolder.isFav)
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fav);

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;
    public Boolean isFav=false;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.length;
}
 }
```

What I see in the output :

[image]

As seen i select first row icon , but after scroll RecyclerView , selected position change.

Then try to use changing `favIcon`and `imgViewIcon.setOnClickListener` in `onCreateViewHolder` again wrong position!

Too i try to store position in sharedPreferences or modelClass , but this return wrong position in scrolling yet

There is a way to avoid this problem?

**I saw this solution Too :[Get clicked item and its position in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use your model `ItemData[] itemsData;` to save if element is selected.

eg.

```
        if (itemsData[position].isFav){

                viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fav);
         }else{

                viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pre_ic_ab_drawer);
         }


viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (!itemsData[position].isFav) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity,"Selected Row : "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            itemsData[position].isFav = true;
                            viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fav);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pre_ic_ab_drawer);
                            itemsData[position].isFav = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: as i said in question , i tried this way before , yet i have problem with adapter

Comment: i don't know why but i used this way before and not work , but now it's work! - thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ItemData[] itemsData;
Activity activity;

public MyAdapter(Activity activity, ItemData[] itemsData) {
    this.activity=activity;
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!viewHolder.isFav) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Selected Row : "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.isFav = true;
                viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fav);
            } else {
                viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pre_ic_ab_drawer);
                viewHolder.isFav = false;
            }
        }
    });


    if (viewHolder.isFav)
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_fav);
    else
        // The change 
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pre_ic_ab_drawer);

}
```

When you bind the ViewHolder you should reset the ImageView icon if it's not *fav*.

Comment: i tried this way before , it not work too - my problem is when click on icon then scroll list